# why does fgets() keep skipping last letter when I dont have an empty line at the end?

Tags: c, fgets

I want to get every line and put it in my array. This works when I have an empty line at the end of the file, but I need to be able to process all lines without having a line at the end. When I read the file the x is missing at the end of ax on the last line. This is the file used:

```
read ax
mul 2 ax
print ax

the file I get with my code:
read ax
mul 2 ax
print a
```

This is what I have at the moment. How can I fix this?

```
int row = 100;
int columns = 100;
char operation[row][columns];
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
//populates matrix of assembly code
while(fgets(operation[i],columns, fp)!=NULL){
  operation[i][strlen(operation[i])-1] = '\0';
  i++;
} numberOfLines = i;

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLines;i++){
   printf("%s\n",operation[i]);
```

}

Comment: You're setting the last character of the line that was read to 0 without making sure it's a newline first...

Comment: [Your step 3 is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60551717/918959)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
operation[i][strcspn(operation[i], "\r\n")] = '\0';
```

This will set the first '\r' or '\n' to '\0'

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcspn.htm

Comment: can you elaborate please?

Comment: where would this work?

Comment: @Julian what do you mean? It will work with any string.

Comment: do i put this after my operation, or do I replace it? Cause when i replaced it with my line i got an error

Comment: @Julian did you include <string.h> ?

Comment: You replace your line with this one.

Comment: oh okay i got it to work thanks!